# DataView doesn't sort ascending or descending in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

The program runs fine but Ascending and Descending buttons don't do anything. The DataGridView with all the data from a table looks the same and not sorted. It suppose to sort by Title. Maybe it does sort but doesn't refresh the DataGridView?

```
private void btnSortAscendingRecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView TitlesDataView = new DataView(booksDataset1.Books);

            TitlesDataView.Sort = "BookTitle ASC";

            //sort asc titles in videosgrid

        }

        private void btnSortDescendingRecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView TitlesDataView = new DataView(booksDataset1.Books);

            TitlesDataView.Sort = "BookTitle DESC";

            //sort descending titles in videosgrid
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the DataSource to the new DataView you just created. I assume this is windows forms application?

If so then:

```
[YourDataGridView].DataSource = TitlesDataView;
```

Answer (score 0):

When **DataGridView** binds to the **DataSource** (*DataView, BindingSource, Table, DataSet+"tablename"*) in all cases it refere to the **DataView**. Get reference to this DataView and set **Sort** (and **Filter**) as you wish:

```
DataView dv = null;
CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)(dgv.BindingContext[dgv.DataSource, dgv.DataMember]);

if (cm.List is BindingSource)
{
    // In case of BindingSource it may be chain of BindingSources+relations
    BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)cm.List;
    while (bs.List is BindingSource)
    { bs = bs.List as BindingSource; }

    if (bs.List is DataView)
    { dv = bs.List as DataView; }
}
else if (cm.List is DataView)
{
    // dgv bind to the DataView, Table or DataSet+"tablename"
    dv = cm.List as DataView;
}

if (dv != null)
{
    dv.Sort = "somedate desc, firstname";
    // dv.Filter = "lastname = 'Smith' OR lastname = 'Doe'";

    //  You can Set the Glyphs something like this:
    int somedateColIdx = 5;    // somedate
    int firstnameColIdx = 3;   // firstname
    dgv.Columns[somedateColIdx].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending;
    dgv.Columns[firstnameColIdx].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
}
```

Note: **Column names used in Sort and Filter correspond to the column names in DataTable**,
Column names in DataGridView are the names of controls used to display cells in dgv.
You can get column name used in DataView like this:

```
string colName = dgv.Columns[colIdx].DataPropertyName
```

Depends of how do you want to track sorted columns (colSequence, colName, asc/desc, dgvColIdx) you may decide how to build Sort and Filter expression and set the SortGlyph in dgv (I made hardcode for simplicity).